# Get Computer Object Properties for the list of servers in a file

Tags: active-directory, filtering, powershell-v4.0

When I run Get-ADComputer cmdlet, I can view all of the single object's properties, like below.

```
C:\PS>Get-ADComputer "Fabrikam-SRV1" -Properties *


AccountExpirationDate              :
accountExpires                     : 9223372036854775807
AccountLockoutTime                 :
AccountNotDelegated                : False
AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption  : False
BadLogonCount                      :
CannotChangePassword               : False
CanonicalName                      : Fabrikam.com/Computers/fabrikam-srv1
```

I then can filter which Properties to display in the output.
Is this possible to get all of the Properties for a list of computer objects in a file (txt or csv) and then filter the needed one?

Something like this `Get-ADComputer -Computer (Get-Content -Path .\computers.txt) | Select CanonicalName,CN,DistinguishedName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible to get all of the Properties for a list of computer objects in a file (txt or csv) and then filter the needed one?

Yes. Assuming the file `computers.txt` contains only a single computer name per-line.

```
Get-Content computers.txt |
  Get-ADComputer -Properties * |
    Select-Object CanonicalName, CN, DistinguishedName
```

Moreover, you can skip the `-Properties *` (could be slow if dealing with many computers) and just choose which properties to retrieve in addition to the default ones. The `DistinguishedName` is included in the default set.

```
Get-ADComputer -Properties CanonicalName, CN
```

If you've a CSV, you'll need to determine *which* column or heading name contains the computer name. If you provide an example formatted CSV, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Assuming the file computers.txt contains only a single computer name per-line, - that's totally correct assumption. Thanks!